# How to get multiple output

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @divisionid varchar(max)

Select @divisionid = code 
from tbl_em_employees 
Where code between 10001 and 10020

Print @divisionid
```

By above query I want to print below output

```
10001
10002
10003
-----
-----
-----
10020
```

How to get this output?

Comment: Please be more specific and format your question better, I can't really tell what you expect as a result.

Comment: If you want to print all the lines separately, you need a loop, for example a cursor, but why are you even using print? How about just using select instead?

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be as simple as

```
  Select  code 
    from tbl_em_employees 
    Where code between 10001 and 10020

    order by code
```

it looks way too obvious.. so i'm not sure if o'm missing something! what is the purpose of the declared variable @divisionid??